# positive integer solutions to $x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3=500$

Tags: combinatorics

When it was given:
$$x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3=30$$
I could do it because $30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ and since there are $3$ options for $3$ distinct divisors, it's easy.

Please write the steps of the solution in detail.

Comment: Please post how you are trying to solve the problem, and what you have attempted. This appears to be a homework question. Have you tried looking at the prime factors of $500$?

Comment: There are more options: don't forget that $1$ is a possibility.

Comment: Are you looking for the number of solutions? Are you looking for a list of solutions? You seem to have the idea already, since you found one solution. What is stopping you from finding the rest?

Comment: How many distinct solutions did you get for $x_1x_2x_3=30$?

Comment: Now what i did is assuming each variable to be 2^x × 3^y.....rest is by ball and sticks method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$500=2^25^3$. Find triples $u_1,u_2,u_3$ so that $u_1 u_2 u_3=2^2$ and $v_1,v_2,v_3$ so that $v_1v_2v_3=5^3$. Then $x_i=u_iv_i$ is a solution to your original equation, and you get all solutions from this process.

There are $\binom{2+3-1}{3-1}=6$ triples $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $\binom{3+3-1}{3-1}=10$ triples $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$. So there are $6\cdot 10=60$ solutions to $x_1x_2x_3=500$, assuming order matters.

Comment: Yup thank you!i got it